# Emacs regex search then write

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I would like to find/extract a group in each line of a buffer, then write it to a new buffer.

So in my comma-delimted data file, my lines basically look like this:

```
'A-field','B-field','C-field','D-field'
```

i.e., four single-quoted fields of data per line. I want to extract the quoted B-field and write it to a new buffer.

Is it possible at the elisp repl to extract from one buffer and write that to a new buffer? Or is this something you'd write as a stand-alone .el file then call from the buffer (M-my-extract-write) from the mini-buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

- copy&paste your file's content to a new buffer.
- in the new buffer do `C-u C-s ^[^,]*,'\([^']*\)',.* M-% \1 RET !`.

Comment: thanks! this worked well. However, it didn't like a field like this: `'Dumb Bells (50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5 lbs.)','Troy','Cardio','none' ` no doubt because of the commas in the field.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) + sexp movements for stuff like this.

Macros also work well, but the immediate feedback of multiple-cursors is nice.

Writing elisp to handle simple repetitive tasks is overkill.

Comment: only problem with multiple cursors is that it doesn't support evil yet. :(